Trouble computing gradient of constraint function in PyTorch for SQUAT adversarial attack algorithm implementation
I am implementing the SQUAT algorithm from a research paper on adversarial attacks using Sequential Quadratic Programming (SQP) with the CVXPY library.. My current task involves calculating the Gradient (∇g) of a constraint function (_) = (_ − 1_. * _)*(_) ≤ 0 where C(x k) represents the classifier’s output (a vector torch.FloatTensor torch.Size([10])), and _j ​is the canonical basis vector for class j.
However, I'm encountering issues with computing the Gradient using PyTorch's torch.autograd.functional.jacobian function. Yes I'm using jacobian because is the only way (apparently) to compute the gradient in this situation (g ∈ R^10). The function returns an all zero value tensor of dimension [10,784] (a matrix) . Below is a snippet of my code where I attempt to compute the Gradient of g:
def squat_algorithm(x, x_k):
    n = 28 * 28
    d = cp.Variable(n)  # direction (variable of the optimization problem)
    I = torch.eye(n)
   
    for k in range(config.N_iter):
        if k < config.N_1:
            f_grad = utils.f_gradient(x, x_k)
            objective = cp.Minimize(cp.matmul(f_grad.t(), d) + 0.5 * cp.quad_form(d, I))
            
            g = cp.Variable(utils.g(x_k).shape, value=utils.g(x_k).numpy()) #THIS IS AN ERROR BUT IS THE ONLY WAY TO RUN THE CODE
            g_grad = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(utils.g, x_k.flatten()).numpy() # HERE
            constraints = [g_grad @ d + g <= 0]  # HERE
            
            problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
            result = problem.solve(solver=cp.OSQP, verbose=False)
            optimal_d = d.value
            
            x_k = x_k.flatten() + (config.α * optimal_d)
            x_k = x_k.clamp(min=0.0, max=1.0).reshape(28, 28).to(torch.float32)


How should I correctly compute the Jacobian of g(x_k) in this context?
Is there a more efficient way to implement this computation in PyTorch, especially considering that g(x_k) involves operations on the output of a neural network?

Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated as I work through this implementation challenge.

g(x_k) involves operations on the neural network output C(x_k), which is a vector of size 10.
The constraint function g(x_k) = (I_k - 1_K.T * e_j) * C(x_k) <= 0 where:
I_k is likely an identity matrix or part of it for dimension considerations.
1_K.T might be a row vector of ones, and e_j is the j-th canonical basis vector.
Steps to Compute Jacobian:
Define g(x_k) in PyTorch: Convert the mathematical expression into a PyTorch function.
Use torch.autograd.functional.jacobian: This function computes the Jacobian matrix of the output with respect to the input.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

def squat_algorithm(x, x_k, classifier, j, config):
    n = 28 * 28  # Assuming MNIST-like input size
    d = cp.Variable(n)  # direction vector
    I = torch.eye(n)
    
    for k in range(config.N_iter):
        if k < config.N_1:
            # Compute gradient of the objective function
            f_grad = utils.f_gradient(x, x_k)
            
            # Define g(x_k) in PyTorch
            def g_func(x):
                C = classifier(x.view(1, 1, 28, 28))  # Reshape if necessary for your classifier
                I_k = torch.eye(10)  # Assuming C(x_k) size is [10]
                one_K_T = torch.ones(1, 10)
                e_j = torch.zeros(10, 1)
                e_j[j] = 1  # j-th basis vector
                return torch.matmul((I_k - one_K_T.t() @ e_j.T), C.view(10)).squeeze()
            
            # Compute Jacobian
            g_jac = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(g_func, x_k.view(-1))
            
            # Convert PyTorch tensor to numpy for CVXPY
            g_value = g_func(x_k).detach().numpy()
            g_jac_np = g_jac.detach().numpy()
            
            objective = cp.Minimize(cp.matmul(f_grad.t(), d) + 0.5 * cp.quad_form(d, I))
            
            # Constraint using the Jacobian
            constraints = [cp.matmul(g_jac_np, d) + g_value <= 0]
            
            problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
            result = problem.solve(solver=cp.OSQP, verbose=False)
            optimal_d = d.value
            
            # Update x_k
            x_k = (x_k.view(-1) + config.α * torch.from_numpy(optimal_d)).clamp(0.0, 1.0).view(28, 28)
    
    return x_k

# Example usage:
class DummyClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DummyClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(784, 10)  # Example for MNIST
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.softmax(self.fc(x.view(x.size(0), -1)), dim=1)

# Assuming you have these:
x = torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28)  # Example input
x_k = torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28)  # Current point
classifier = DummyClassifier()
config = type('Config', (), {})()
config.N_iter = 10
config.N_1 = 5
config.α = 0.1
j = 3  # Class index for e_j

# Call the function
result = squat_algorithm(x, x_k, classifier, j, config)
print(result)

